# AUCTeX on Windows: LaTeX found no preview images

Tags: auctex

I realize questions along this line have been answered before, but I couldn't an answer that worked for me.  My setup:

- Windows 7
- emacs 25.3 - the GNU windows build (not Xwindows, not cygwin)
- cygwin used for unix toolchain in Emacs, e.g. grep (not MinGW)
- MikTex 2.9 for LaTeX - fresh install from scratch yesterday (long story)

I have a short .tex file, with a few math expressions which AUCTeX preview should generate images for.  From Emacs, I can compile the file (i.e. run pdflatex) no problem.  When I make previews for buffer, latex runs fine, but then I get:

```
Transcript written on _region_.log.

TeX Output exited as expected with code 1 at Mon Jun  4 06:46:49
LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
```

And no previews appear.

So - any thoughts, or advice for how to diagnose this?

Comment: Which AUCTeX version do you use?  And how did you install it?  Which Ghostscript version are you using?

Comment: AucTex version 12.1.1, installed via elpa/melpa.  Which ghostscript version?  Hmm., how would I find out exactly which version *auctex* is using / finding?  Thanks.